# Возврат объекта List из метода

Tags: c#

Как правильно возвращать объект List из метода? Если просто сделать List выходным параметром, не получится ли операция слишком тяжелой за счет копирования значений локальной переменной метода наружу?

Comment: >Если просто сделать List выходным параметром, не получится ли операция слишком тяжелой за счет копирования значений локальной переменной метода наружу?

почему? вы же сами ниже пишете, что экземпляры классов передаются по ссылке (и это действительно так). Соответственно, затраты будут заключаться в копировании адреса, каким бы большим ни был List

Comment: @DreamChild: Объясните мне механизм, как компилятор понимает, когда локальные объекты надо удалять после завершения метода, а когда не удалять. В С++ память под локальные объекты освобождается, как только поток выполнения выходит из области видимости объекта. А как в C#?

Comment: @DarkGenius это довольно обширная тема, поэтому советую вам почитать про сборщик мусора (да-да, этим занимается именно сборщик, а не компилятор). Основная идея - пока остаются ссылки на переменную, она остается жива-здорова

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы генерируете список внутри некоего метода, то best practices предлагают делать так:

```
public void DoSomeWork()
{
    List<Double> someList = new List<Double>();
    // fill someList with values
    int someInt = (new Random).Next();
    Dictionary<Double,Double> someDict = calc_distribution(someList, someInt);
}
```

Т.е. вы сначала **не** инициализируете ваш Dictionary нуллом или пустым словарем, т.е. избавляетесь от лишних проверок или переприсваивания.

А вот если вам нужно изменить уже имеющийся словаре someDict, как он указан в моём примере, то имеет смысл передавать его по ссылке в метод. Подробнее почитать можно тут: [Передача аргумента по ссылке - ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/14akc2c7.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @Drac5: Разве в C# объекты не передаются по ссылке по умолчанию?

Comment: Тогда покажите для начала код, чтобы было понятно, что вы делали. Если вы в методе создаете объект List, а затем передаете его выходным параметром, то после копирования экземпляр из метода попадет на первый уровень сборщика мусора.И очень-очень скоро будет очищен. Давайте код, будем говорить конкретно.

Comment: @Drac5: Вот пример: http://pastebin.com/Wss8j2pR
Правда, здесь возвращается словарь, но суть вопроса не меняется.

Comment: @DarkGenius, а как вызываете этот метод?
Обновил ответ, как я вижу вызов вашего метода. Естественно, заполнение передаваемых параметров за вами.

Comment: @Drac5: Метод вызывается в main. 
Вы привели пример вызова: "Dictionary<Double,Double> someDict = calc_distribution(someList, someInt);".
То есть в этом случае компилятор понимает, что локальный объект будет использоваться извне метода и создаст объект сразу в нужной области памяти?

Comment: @DarkGenius, someDist будет инициализирован только после того, как метод calc_distribution вернет некоторый список. На этом в данном случае и будет происходить экономия.

Answer (score 1):

Лист хранит в себе ссылки на объекты, а не сами объекты. Поэтому каким бы большим у вас лист ни был, копирования локальных переменных "наружу", т.е. создание новых экземпляров-копий 
не произойдёт, и о производительности в данном случае беспокоиться не стоит.

Если всё же сомневаетесь, попробуйте инициализировать новый лист до вызова вашего метода и передавать его туда в качестве аргумента, а заполнять его уже в методе. При этом возвращать его не обязательно (метод может ничего не возвращать). По завершении метода у вас будет заполненный вашими данными лист.

Comment: @Alexey Grebenyukov: Но ведь объекты у нас созданы локально для метода. Когда выполняется присвоение List<double> list = GetList(), в list будут скопированы значения или же локальные переменные освободятся сборщиком мусора и объект list будет некорректен?

Comment: В лист будут скопированы ссылки на переменные. И я напомню, что объект существует (т.е. не удаляется сборщиком мусора), пока на него существует хотя бы одна ссылка.